# Why won't this combination of MySQL and PHP work?

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone tell me if the following MySQL procedure along with a PHP script work?

I've set up mysql procedure here and I think it makes sense but the PHP script will print error. By that I'm guessing that there were 0 rows effected?

MySQL:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE procedure spPlayer (IN pName NVARCHAR(50), IN pMobileNumber NVARCHAR(50), IN pTime datetime, OUT pID INT)
begin

select count(*) into @cnt FROM tblnewusers;
IF @cnt < 12 THEN
    insert into tblplayers (Name, MobileNumber, Time)
    values
    (pName, pMobileNumber, pTime);
    SELECT pID = @@IDENTITY;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$dt = new datetime();
$name = "Test";
$mobile = "1234567";
$time = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$dbhost = 'dbHost here';
$dbuser = 'dbUser here';
$dbpass = 'dbPass here';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn)
{
    die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());
}   

mysql_select_db("SafeDropbox", $conn);

$result = mysql_query("CALL spPlayer();");

if($result) {
    echo "Success";
}
else {
    echo "Error";   
}

?>
```

EDIT
Here's the MySql table set up it it helps!

[image]

Comment: To make it easier to answer your question (and increase the chances someone will make the effort to) please always include the error message you're getting.

Comment: Well you see there isn't an error message. I've got the script on my server, I literally point to the script and it page prints put error

Comment: can you echo $result and let us know what it displays?

Comment: It displays blank unfortunately. I just wrote `echo $result;` and nothing

Comment: If PHP reports an error, it is not because of 0 rows returned, but rather a syntax problem or other error with the procedure. Are you able to run the SP without PHP?

Comment: @user3907211 `$result` will either be boolean false (which is what's happening here) or a mysql_result resource object if the SP call succeeds.

Comment: @RobGleeson Blank output from `echo $result;` is expected because it's value is `false`. If you `var_dump($output)` you would see `(boolean) false`.  Instead you need to `echo mysql_error();`  My assumption is you'll see errors relating to the SP arguments. You defined the procedure to accept several input args, but did not supply any with `CALL()`

Comment: mysql_error() returned this "ErrorIncorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE safedropbox.spPlayer; expected 4, got 0"

Comment: think there could be an error in this line CREATE procedure spPlayer (IN pName NVARCHAR(50), IN pMobileNumber NVARCHAR(50), IN pTime datetime, OUT pID INT)

Comment: It looks like there isn't any parameters being passed into the procedure?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: i think you may have to set the arguments here i could be wrong $result = mysql_query("CALL spPlayer();");
is said you were expected 4 but got zero in return, so maybe it has to be CALL spPlayer(argument1,argument2,argument3,argument4)

Comment: Yea that's what I was thinking too. I'll give a go soon and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

This is an assumption answer, and this could definetly be more detailed and refined:

When you `echo mysql_error();`it produces the following error for you:

> ErrorIncorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE safedropbox.spPlayer;
>   expected 4, got 0

When you created your procedure you set it with 4 arguments:

```
CREATE procedure spPlayer (IN pName NVARCHAR(50), IN pMobileNumber NVARCHAR(50), IN pTime datetime, OUT pID INT)
```

Hence, when you call it you might need to provide `spPlayer` with with 4 arguments as well:

```
$result = mysql_query("CALL spPlayer();");
```

Comment: When I add `$result = mysql_query("CALL spPlayer( $name, $mobile, $time);");` nothing prints out now, not even the myaql_error()